# How to use React HOC with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new with Typescript and i want to  using React HOC(Higher-Order Components). I need to wrap every component with function intlWrapper to provider context named IntlContext. My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import  {IntlContext} from '../intl';
export default function intlWrapper <T> (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<T>){
  return class IntlReceiver extends React.Component <T>{
    render() {
      return (
        <IntlContext.Consumer>
          {
            locale=><WrappedComponent {...this.props} locale={locale}/>
          }
        </IntlContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But i got an complie error.

```
(10,55): Property 'locale' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<T, any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<T>'.
```

If i change  to any, the code works. But when i use WrappedComponent, the PropTypes defined in interface lost because of it is wrapped. 
Is there any solutions to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<T>` There is no guarantee that the component class takes the `locale` property.

You can ensure that by adding it e.g. `WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<T & {locale:SomeTypeThatLocaleIs}>` etc.